# How to continue a suspend function in a dynamic proxy in the same coroutine?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I want to continue a suspend function in a dynamic proxy in the same coroutine.
Please have a look at the following code:

```
interface Adder {
    suspend fun add(a: Int, b: Int): Int
}

val IH = InvocationHandler { _, method, args ->
    val continuation = args.last() as Continuation<*>
    val realArgs = args.take(args.size - 1)
    println("${method.name}$realArgs")
    GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(5_000)
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST") (continuation as Continuation<Int>).resume(3)
    }
    COROUTINE_SUSPENDED
}

fun main() {
    val adder = Proxy.newProxyInstance(
        Adder::class.java.classLoader, arrayOf(Adder::class.java), IH
    ) as Adder
    runBlocking {
        println(adder.add(1, 2))
    }
}
```

It works fine. It runs the delay function in a new coroutine.
However, that's not what I want.

I want to run the InvocationHandler in the same coroutine as the one that was started with runBlocking.
Something like:

```
val IH = InvocationHandler { _, _, _ ->
    delay(5_000)
    3
}
```

This obviously won't compile because delay is a suspend function that must be run in a coroutine.
So the question is: How could I write the InvocationHandler for my intended behavior?
Any help would be very much appreciated.

I'd like to use this code in my RPC framework.
My real code would replace the delay call with non-blocking Ktor socket calls for serializing the data over the wire.
You can find the code example  at: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/softappeal/yass/master/kotlin/yass/test/ch/softappeal/yass/remote/SuspendProxy.kt

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution for my problem:

```
package ch.softappeal.yass

import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.lang.reflect.*
import kotlin.coroutines.*
import kotlin.test.*

typealias SuspendInvoker = suspend (method: Method, arguments: List<Any?>) -> Any?

private interface SuspendFunction {
    suspend fun invoke(): Any?
}

private val SuspendRemover = SuspendFunction::class.java.methods[0]

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <C : Any> proxy(contract: Class<C>, invoker: SuspendInvoker): C =
    Proxy.newProxyInstance(contract.classLoader, arrayOf(contract)) { _, method, arguments ->
        val continuation = arguments.last() as Continuation<*>
        val argumentsWithoutContinuation = arguments.take(arguments.size - 1)
        SuspendRemover.invoke(object : SuspendFunction {
            override suspend fun invoke() = invoker(method, argumentsWithoutContinuation)
        }, continuation)
    } as C

interface Adder {
    suspend fun add(a: Int, b: Int): Int
}

class SuspendProxyTest {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val adder = proxy(Adder::class.java) { method, arguments ->
            println("${method.name}$arguments")
            delay(100)
            3
        }
        runBlocking { assertEquals(3, adder.add(1, 2)) }
    }
}
```

Any comments?
Is this a good/problematic solution?
Could/should the "removing of suspend functionality" be added to the `kotlin.coroutines` library?